# Video files are not Streaming using MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming, avplayer, avplayerlayer

How can i do streaming of video files using AVPlayerlayer?

Comment: Did your ISP block google.com?

Comment: no , its not blocking...

Comment: hi.. audio files streaming is possible but video files are not streaming....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer to stream the songs.

https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

For videos you could use `MPMoviePlayerController`:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:streamURL];
[player play];
```

Comment: ya it is good for audio files but i want to stream videos files along with audio files in my All songs list...

Comment: Edited answer for video streaming.